# Notification iOs Push delivered?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, swift3

I recently set up notifications on my application, I can send via php and no worries, everything works fine.

Since last week, I am trying to find out if a push notification is received by the phone or not..

I can know when someone clicks on it but if the person does not click on it and prefer to open the application, it does not work..

Is there not a simple function that can tell me if a notification has just been received by the application ?

In my AppDelegate.swift :

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     // Check if launched from notification
     if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
       //print(notification)
       window?.rootViewController?.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
   } 
   else{
       //print("ici ?")
       registerForRemoteNotification()
   }

return true
}

...

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
     completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     completionHandler()
}

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        **print("here ?")**

        switch((application.applicationState)){

        case UIApplicationState.inactive:
            print("Inactive")
            //Show the view with the content of the push
            completionHandler(.newData)

        case UIApplicationState.background:
            print("Background")
            //Refresh the local model
            completionHandler(.newData)

        default:
            print("Active")
            //Show an in-app banner
            completionHandler(.newData)
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Problem : I never pass in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** :/
The "print here" is never displayed.

I have a mistake on this line :

> Instance method
>   'application(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)'
>   nearly matches optional requirement
>   'application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)'
>   of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

But I do not understand :/

Do you have an idea ?

Thx for your help ^^

Comment: whatever you said in your third explanation , only we can check user tap the   notification. when user swipe the notification cant check,  This feature not available in apple document.

Comment: it's not possible to check if my app receive a push ? O_o

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830597/how-to-know-push-notification-delivery-status  , go with link and i studied also no guarantee to say delivered or not.  In our app also we tried this one , that time i came to know not possible, only when user tap that one then only.

Comment: I read the link but I have the opposite example : How does WhatsApp detect if a message is delivered without opening the app on iOS ?

It should be possible :p

Answer (score 2):

It's rather common mistake since the conversion to Swift 3 - you're using Swift 2 method.

The right signature of this method in Swift 3 is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("here?")
}
```

Comment: Oh it's just a bad copy/paste... in my code, it's the right signature, for Swift 3..
My bad ^^
But it's still doesn't work :/

Comment: are you running it in iOS 10?

Comment: Do you physically get pushes for this app? With sound etc.

Comment: Yes, the pushes work fine but i don't know how to "catch" when it delivered on the phone :/

Comment: What for do you need to "catch"? If user taps on push the app should know this either in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if app was terminated or in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` if app was in background

Comment: When i say "catch", it's when the phone receive the push.. without action of user.

Check my code, is it good for you ?
Because it didn't work in didReceiveRemoteNotification and i don't know how fix it :/

(thx for your time ^^)

Comment: Have you implemented the methods: `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {}` and `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {}`? We should know for sure that if the app registered for remote notifications or not

Comment: Yes, the methods are implemented and the pushs work fine when i send via my php script.. 
I receive notifications.

but i never pass in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" :/

Comment: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called in two cases: 1. app is in background and user taps on push 2. app is active and 'silent push' is received