# how we know that notification reached to iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am sending notification to multiple iOS devices. is there any method to know that user actually received notification and user clicked the notification?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830597/how-to-know-push-notification-delivery-status

Comment: @PiyushRathi   Thanks for your answer, this only works when user clicks the notification.

Comment: Your app will be noticed only if the user clicks the notification.

Comment: There's no way to know if the **user** received the notification. However, if it's a background notification, you can now that the **device** received it using the appropriate delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do that because APNS will just send-out push notifications to target tokens. There is some validation process there to report the tokens go invalid.

I think you should implement your own logic to do that, so when notification is tapped, you will get your callback called :
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application
and call your backend(notification sender) that user actually tapped the notification.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Is there any way to know when user not clicked the notification.

Comment: I am not sure there will be a way to detect that, because notification will remain in your notification panel until you tap on it or clear all of them - which can't be detected.

Comment: When app is in background or active, we can detect when notification is shown to user. But when app is closed completely, no way to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some handler to user click the notification event - and there you can perform some action like sending request to your server about this event

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this only works when user clicks the notification.

Comment: Is there any way to know when user not clicked the notification.

Comment: Yes, you can handle user click event - but no notification receiving event

Answer (score 0):

As explained by christian, You can develop your own logic by following below 2 steps:

**1)** When user get the notification, Push notification's delegate method, for objective-c

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

And For Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

become active. In this method a web service call can be called with some parameters to identify the message in notification.

**2)**After first step is completed and user click on the notification to read the message then again you can call another web service with some parameters to identify that the user have read the message. For this you can write the web service logic in, for objective-c:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

And for swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void)
```