# Delivery report of sending remote push notifications using APNS - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending remote push notifications using APNS. The requirement is when the notification is delivered to the app user (even if the user did not tapped on the notification or even seen it) , send a delivery receipt to the web server (i.e. call a web service) according to the notification id i received.

APNS did not have a provision of delivery reports. Their is a feedback service of APNS, however that does not offer delivery report either.

So i would like to know what are the possible ways to get a delivery report of remote push notifications. If i am able to execute a custom method in APP deligate or any other when a remote push notification arrives  even when the APP is in background or terminated by user then it will solve my problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Below is the code i am using currently and it is not working when the app is in background.

I wrote a custom method in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

to send confirmation to the server that the notification is received. When the application is in foreground all functions execute perfectly. But the problem arise when the application is in background. The custom method which is written in

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

does not execute until the user open the application by tapping the notification bar and never execute if the user open the application by tapping the app icon not by the notification bar.

Comment: Seems, that you are thinking in the right way. You can run some custom methods to notify about delivery when application is in foreground. But while app is in background only iOS can handle push notifications and there is no way to notify about delivery.

Comment: You need to see `content-available=1` in your notification payloa disorder to deliver the remote notification to the app when it is suspended. If the app is terminated then the app will not be notified about the notification arrival.

Answer (score 20):

Since Apple doesn't provides any method to know when a Push Notification has delivered to user's device. Here is what you can do,

1) Add **"Notification Service Extension"** to your app.

2) Now add your code for calling webservice to report to your server about the Notification being received, in **didReceiveNotificationRequest**.

3) Now go to **Capabilities** of your app and enable **"Background fetch**" in **"Background Modes"**.

4) Now with the notification you are sending, pass **"content-available = 1"**, This will wake up your app for 30 sec and it can execute the code written in **didReceiveNotificationRequest**.

It worked for me.

Comment: what will be the behavior when the app is killed manually from the app switcher?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to know this? What purpose does it serve you to know whether or not they actually received the notification on their device?

In any case, use: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8

It will wake your app for 30 seconds in the background to handle it. You need to add the RemoteNotifications background capability.

If too many are sent per hour, Apple will throttle them or just not deliver them.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add the Notification Service Extension anymore!

#### ✅ It's natively possible from 2023 and there are tools for this now

[image: Monitor Delivery Metrics]

Apple introduced [**Push Notification Console**](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/push-notifications-console) in 2023 with a bunch of features and APIs. One of them is **Monitor delivery metrics** which you can get the different states of a notification by giving the **apns-unique-id**. [Here is the WWDC video moment about this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10025/?time=368).

With this feature, you can **even find out why it is NOT delivered** in some cases (for example when the [Low Power mode is on](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023-10025/?time=394)). All delivery logs (including console and API) are available in the Delivery Log tab of the console:

[image: Console Demo]

This feature is available for notifications sent through **regular APNs API** as well. You need to record **“apns-unique-id”** from APNs response to be able to query this information.

<sub>⚠️ Note that for the notifications sent from the Console, there’s no need to switch to the “delivery log” tab, the same information is available on the Send page itself:</sub>

[image: Console Demo 2]