# iOS: Notification Badge Number does not reset

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to reset the notification badge number whenever the app is opened. This works perfectly fine calling

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

However, when I one ore more new notifications come in, the icon badge number again goes to 42 no matter how many notifications come in.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What badge value does your notification contain?

Comment: Honnestly I Don't really know how I can look this up

Comment: Check with your server guy, or the one sending push notification. It comes with payload in "badge" key.

Comment: Ok so I set it to 1 (it obviouly was 42 before). How can I now achieve that the badge number increases per notification that is received?

Comment: @ktm125 It would be difficult to maintain the exact count. But there are workarounds/Cracks for it too(Which might not work perfectly all the time).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of the following for achieving this,

1. You can store notifications received in your database and when user opens app, you can get the count of unread notifications and update the count.
2. If you are targeting single users then, you can get the delivery of Push notifications using https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797 and then when the notification is opened you can pass notification Open event to server. So the next time the server sends push notification, they can just check for the difference in Deliver and Open and send that count in badge. If user has cleared all notifications from Notification centre without opening them. In that case as soon as App opens you need to update that at server, Else you might be getting wrong count from server.