# I Need to call an API after receiving notification (app is in open, background, in active) using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I Need to call an API after receiving notification (an app is in open, background, inactive)

If the app is in open it is working fine
But if the app is in the background, inactive it is not working

The following method will call when presenting notification in the foreground

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { }
```

The following method will call once we tap on the received notification

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

So, how can I call API once I receive notification when an app is in the background, inactive

Comment: If the app is "not running", I don't think you can run any code, since you don't get any control inside your app.

Comment: Try this solution ,it might be something you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797

Answer (score 0):

- When App will be in background mode this method will not be called, then user needs to tap on the notification then it will be called.
- You need to integrate Apple pushkit which will send silent notifications to device & inside its delegate method you can call the API

  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit