# Feedback Notification (iOS)

Tags: ios, notifications, feedback

One of my application have 70k+ users and I am sending notifications to them but it is taking more than 7 hours to send a notification to all users.

So, I want to check out of them how many users have installed my application and how many users have to remove it from the mobile.

For that, I research some things and find out **Feedback Notification** will use for that.
But I don't know how it works and implements in iOS.

Could anyone please suggest me some details for the same or also suggest any other way how I can find users who have removed my app from the mobile.

Comment: You can use silent push notifications and monitor its response from APNS in order to get the actual active users on your App.

Comment: But how we can make sure silent notification is successfully delivered to that user or not?

Comment: When you send push notification from your server, APNS reverts back with success and failure for device tokens. So all the device tokens that gets failed, can be removed for further use. But if you want to get the Delivery report of Push Notification ref:, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797

Comment: Yes, We can do this with your suggestion.
But in existing application version we have no such kind of functionality.
We can do it from a new version of our application.