# How can I get all the iOS push notifications and not just the last one when the app comes back online?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, push

Apple doc says that if there are multiple notifications to be delivered then only the last notification will be delivered to the phone because the Queue size is 1. So If my app goes offline and there are like 40 notifications to be delivered, when my app comes online I only get one notification instead of all 40.

I have tested this with WhatsApp and it gets all the notifications even though the app is killed.

How can I ensure I receive all the notifications as well?

Comment: When your notification gets delivered send a delivery report of that notification with your notification ID, Your server will check for all the notification that were not delivered and will send them again. For delivery refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797

Comment: You shouldn't rely on notifications to deliver data. You should send a silent notification and use that to trigger your app to fetch all new data from your server and display local notification(s) as required.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not relying on notifications for data but all I want is guaranteed delivery of notifications when the internet is on again. Currently my phone only gets last notification when internet comes back again

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Notifications are data. They may data that is shown to the user, but it is still data. You can't rely on receiving notifications. You will only get the last one sent if your device is offline while multiple notifications are sent.

Comment: That is what I said @Paulw11. Whatsapp receives all notifications all the times, how can my app do that?

Comment: Use the approach that I outlined or the technique suggested by @manishsharma93. That is what WhatsApp will be doing.

Comment: But if my app is in killed state how would WhatsApp even know that I am back online and I should start receiving all notifications and not just the last one?

Comment: @ShubhamGoel When you come online your last notification will be delivered. You cam send the delivery report of that notification ID to your server and your server will send the remaining notifications to your device.

Comment: @manishsharma93 Do you think my app receives the notification when the app is in killed state, for me to send an acknowledgement to server? No, The app is killed, I cannot receive that notification into my app for me to perform some action untill I launch the app

Comment: @ShubhamGoel Do you know you can perform actions when your app is killed. Please read about Notification Service Extention.

Comment: Can I fetch data into my app with this notification extension when my app is killed? @manishsharma93

Comment: @ShubhamGoel Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195931/discussion-between-shubham-goel-and-manishsharma93).

Comment: @ShubhamGoel did you find the solution?