# Can we call api on silent notification in background?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, silent-notification

Is that possible to call API to send data to the server while getting silent push-notification in iOS? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make an API call after receiving a silent push.However, it does not work if the app is killed by the user. If that is a problem, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202487/11881779)

If that is not the case, here is how to do it. You need to enable 'Background Fetch' and 'Remote Notifications' from Background Modes on Application Capabilities screen on XCode.

Then, add this [application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) method into your AppDelegate.You can make your API call inside this method.

Ex:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

   apiCall(fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)

}
func apiCall(fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){

  //Make call here

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)

}
```

Comment: You can call a service when your app is killed. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044201/5084797