# [iOS][push notification] not receiving notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My situation is my app does not receive push notification after this process:

1. quit app, app is in background
2. open too many other apps so that my app is killed in background, or just use double tap home button to simulate that
3. enter airplane mode, simulating the user being in elevator or smth like that
4. **quit airplane mode, phone reconnect to internet**
5. send a push notification to my app, no push notification is received.

This is actually a very common case for me, especially when the user is using old phones with low memory and background apps are constantly killed.

I have tested with other apps(facebook, twitter, etc) and they all work but mine isn't, is there anything I'm missing?

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my bad grammar.

** update: sorry I made a mistake, I forgot to mention step 4 = =

Comment: Why one should get push notification in an airplane mode?

Comment: = =sorry i forgot to mention #4

Comment: Well, APNS is not garanteed to be delivered at all. Unfortunately there is not even an official time span for how long it is held on the servers or how often they resend the notification.
If a new notification is sent to APNS for delivery then the old notification data is lost and replaced by the new data if its undelivered. If the notification is delivered then also the old notification data is deleted on the APNS server. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731826/any-option-to-know-if-apple-app-get-the-push-notification

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its only for quite notifications but since iOS 8 or 7 you can enable background mode for push notifications. Did you enable that in -> your project -> Capabilities -> Background Modes ?

Comment: I only used "background fetch" for background modes, is that sufficient for displaying alerts and updating banners when in background?